# saving computed number registers for access outside body of "let" operation

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

Section 14.15 of the PGF manual (pp 150-) describes the `let` operation. On pg 152 (first example) it is applied to saving coordinate (tuple values) to point registers `p1` and `p2` using the `coordinate` function to enable accessing computed coordinates outside the body of the `let` operation. It seems to me that it should be possible to save and reuse number registers in a similar fashion, but that does not appear to be the case. See proposed code below. I want to use the computed length `\n1` as the length of the subrectangle `DATASET`, but this does not seem possible within the constraints of this syntax. Ideas? Workarounds?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, positioning, calc}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5em}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
  \tikzstyle{file} = [ellipse, rounded corners, minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em, align=center, draw]
  \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=2em, minimum width=15em, align=center, draw]
  \node [block, minimum height=10em] (DB){\textbf{Database}};
  % Set coordinate points for sub-rectangles
  % See pg 420 of 2.10 PGF manual for anchors
  % 'let' is defined on pg 150 in Section 14.15 (The Let Operation)
  \path
  let
  \p1 = ($(DB.east)$),
  \p2 = ($(DB.west)$),
  \n1 = {veclen(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)/2}
  in
  coordinate(p1) at (\p1)
  coordinate(p2) at (\p2)
  %number(n1) at (\n1) % illustrative syntax
  ;
  % Use n1 for 'minimum width' instead of 2em
  \node [block, draw, minimum width=2em] (DATASET) at ($(DB.north)!2/7!(DB.south)$) {Dataset};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a `.code` key like

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/savenumber/.code 2 args={\global\edef#1{#2}}}
```

which allows you to use

```
[savenumber={<macro to save to>}{<macro to save>}]
```

(note the square brackets) somewhere in a TikZ path (including during a `let` operation).

Your example would thus look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, positioning, calc}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5em}%

\pgfkeys{/tikz/savenumber/.code 2 args={\global\edef#1{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
  \tikzstyle{file} = [ellipse, rounded corners, text width=12em, text height=3em, minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em, align=center, draw]
  \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, rounded corners, text width=12em, text height=3em, minimum height=2em, minimum width=15em, align=center, draw]
  \node [block, minimum height=10em] (DB){\textbf{Database}};
  % Set coordinate points for sub-rectangles
  % See pg 420 of 2.10 PGF manual for anchors
  % 'let' is defined on pg 150 in Section 14.15 (The Let Operation)
  \path
  let
  \p1 = ($(DB.east)$),
  \p2 = ($(DB.west)$),
  \n1 = {veclen(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)/2}
  in
  coordinate(p1) at (\p1)
  coordinate(p2) at (\p2)
  [savenumber={\n}{\n1}]
  ;
  % Use n1 for 'minimum width' instead of 2em
  \node [block, draw, minimum width=\n] (DATASET) at ($(DB.north)!2/7!(DB.south)$) {Dataset};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Jake. You didn't change the last line, which uses the saved value. I assume one would replace `2em` with `\n`? Could one use `n1` instead of `\n`? So, is there any reason a function like my `number` does not exist?

Comment: @Faheem: Sorry, missed changing that line. Fixed now. Can't tell you why such a function doesn't exist. You could just define a new macro `\newcommand\savenumber{[savenumber={#1}{#2}]}` to wrap around the key I suggest in my answer, and then you've basically got your `number` function.

Comment: @Faheem: And missed your question about the macro name: I'm not quite sure what you mean with "Could one use `n1` instead of `\n`. You can use whatever macro name you want, as long as it's a legal TeX macro name, so it needs to have the backslash in front, and can't have a number; `n1` would therefore not work.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works, but the \newcommand you suggested doesn't. I get `ERROR: Illegal parameter number in definition of \savenumber.`

Comment: @Faheem: Sorry, it should be `\newcommand\savenumber[2]{[savenumber={#1}{#2}]}` (I forgot the `[2]`, which specifies the number of parameters).

Comment: Thanks. I should have been able to figure that out myself. Color me lazy.