# Scope inside TikZ axis environment shifted/x,y scaling broken

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, scoping

This is a further follow up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312742/pgfplots-scope-inside-axis-environment-follow-up):

When using a shifted scope within an axis environment, the `(0,0)` coordinate is not at the position where I shifted the scope to:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0}]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=20,
        xmax=170,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=130]
    \node[green] at (160,83) {x};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(160,83)}]
        \node[red] at (0,0) {x};
    \end{scope}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to the linked question I managed to get it working by "redefining" the axis scales:

`\begin{scope}[shift={(160,83)}, x={(1,0)}, y={(0,1)}]`

[image]

But why is this needed? Can anyone please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `axis` coordinate `(0,0)` is not at the coordinates `(0,0)` of the ambient `tikzpicture`, so you need to account for that. Here is one way of doing this.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0}]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=20,
        xmax=170,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=130]
    \node[green] at (160,83) {x};
    \begin{scope}[shift={($(160,83)-(0,0)$)}]
        \node[red] at (0,0) {o};
    \end{scope}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works! But how can I now rotate the scope?
`\begin{scope}[shift={($(160,83)-(0,0)$)}, rotate=90] \node[red] at (0,0) {o}; \node[black] at (10,0) {x};`
does not work as intended...

Comment: @F1iX It is the same reason why it does not work. You need `\begin{scope}[shift={($(160,83)-(0,0)$)}, rotate around={90:(0,0)}] 
  \node[red] at (0,0){o}; \node[black] at (10,0) {x};
 \end{scope}`, i.e. rotate around the `(0,0)` of the *axis*.