# Why will arc not accept \n1 as a radius?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This MWE does work which tells me the let operation is correctly defined.

```
    \documentclass{amsart}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
    let \n1 ={2}
    in
    coordinate [label= $N$] (B) at (\n1,\n1); %to show that \n1 does work as a value
     \draw (0,0)  arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=2];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
\end{document}
```

The one below differs from that only by using \n1 to specify the radius.  But it returns an error message of

! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfk@/tikz/x radius ->\n

```
\documentclass{amsart}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
    let \n1 ={2}
    in
    coordinate [label= $N$] (B) at (\n1,\n1); %to show that \n1 does work as a value
     \draw (0,0)  arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=\n1];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
\end{document}
```

As @Zarko says, the syntax of the first picture is not exactly what the  manual recommends. But this syntax is working for me in a specific tikzpicture with a much more complicated let operation.  Here it is.  Notice that commands after the let operation succeed at use thing base on \p1 through \p4 (so I think savenumber might work for me, if I figure out how) but the arc command will not let me use a value \n1:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path % Given endpoints \p1 and \p2 and the placement of the divide       everything but the semicircle radius is calculated
    let
    \p1 = (-2.2,0),
    \p2 = (2.2,0),
    \p{divide} = ($ (\p1) !.7! (\p2) $),
    \p{center} = ($ (\p1) !.5! (\p2) $), % center of the semicircle
    \p3 = ($ (\x1,{\x{divide}-\x2}) $),
    \p4 =  ($ (\x{divide},\y3) $)
    in
    coordinate [label= left:$B$] (B) at (\p1)
    coordinate  [label= right:$F$] (F) at (\p2)
    coordinate  [label= left:$C$] (C) at (\p3)
    coordinate  [label= right:$D$] (D) at (\p4)
    coordinate  [label= below right:$E$] (E) at (\p{divide})
    coordinate (M) at (\p{center});  %the midpoint M is not labelled in the drawing

    \path [name path=R] (E) -- ($(E) + 1*(0,2.5)$);%upper bound here is set by hand

    \draw (F) [name path=P] arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=2.2];%radius here is set by hand

    \draw [name intersections={of=P and R, by={[label=above:$H$]H}}];

    \draw[dashed]  (0,0) -- (H);
    \draw (B) -- (F) -- (H) --(B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (H);  %all the solid straight lines
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
    \end{document}
```

I need this tikzpicture for use in a publication.  I could just use it the way I have currently written it and publish.  But this version is inelegant because when I want to alter it a little to see what proportions look best I have to recalculate one radius by hand.  If there is a way to get arc to accept \n1 as a radius value the same way as ``coordinate'' does does, with this syntax for let, then I will use that.

Comment: `\n1` will not be available in the rest of the picture after the current path with `let` operation is finished. In other words, next line with `\draw` will not know about the previous `\p{}` and `\n{}` macros.

Comment: What is the more complicated tikzpicture you're trying to make? In any case, does the solution in this [Jake's answer work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27839/4778)? I think it's the best you can get in this situation.

Comment: @Alenanno  Yes, savenumber looks like it might work for me.  I will see.

Comment: Add `\pgfmathsetmacro{\circleradius}{2.2}` e.g. at the start of the `tikzpicture`, and use `\circleradius` instead of `2.2` everywhere.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Thanks, But that is the radius that I would like to be able to vary when I change \p1 and \p2, without just recalculating the radius by hand.

Comment: Well, you use `\circleradius` in `\p1` and `\p2` as well of course, so you have `\p1=(-\circleradius,0),\p2=(\circleradius,0)`.

Comment: Please, see your code again! You in it do exactly the same as I suggest in my answer ... All later used coordinates (`B`,  `C`, ...) are defined in one `\path let ...` block. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @Zarko  Yes, that is what works in the code I have, but I cannot get it to work for the radius of the circle $F$, because I have to draw a line and calculate an intersection to find the radius.

Comment: you need define radious inside block `let`. `\n1` is not valid outside it. by the way, this arc you can named, so as you named other lines.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Good point Maybe I should redesign around that.  In fact just now percusse has done that in his answer, and that way eliminated my use of let altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save whatever value you like into macros with various ways. You don't need to hack any let in machinary. But your picture is also pretty algorithmic so you don't need to save intermediate values that much, here is an alternative take

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\def\myradius{2.2}
\draw[name path=P] (0,0) coordinate(o)+(\myradius,0) coordinate[label=0:$F$] (f) 
    arc(0:180:\myradius) coordinate[label=180:$B$](b) --($(b)!0.7!(f)$) 
    coordinate[label=-45:$E$] (e) --cycle;
\draw(e)--($(e)!1!-90:(f)$) coordinate[label=0:$C$] -| (b) coordinate[label=180:$D$,pos=0.5];
\path [name path=R,overlay] (e) -- ++(0,1.5*\myradius);
\draw [dashed,name intersections={of=P and R, by=h}] (h)coordinate[label=60:$H$] -- (o);
\draw (b) -- (h) -- (f) (e) -- (h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now two variables, `\myradius` and `0.7` defines the whole picture.

[image]

Comment: Terrific.  This teaches me about declaring coordinates inside a draw command, and calculating an intersection inside a draw command.  I had not figured either of those out before.

Answer (score 6):

You have wrong syntax. Try the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw let \n1 = {2} in
        coordinate[label=above:$N$] (B) at (\n1,\n1)
        (0,0)  arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** 
from TikZ manual:

> Note that the effect of a let operation is local to the body of the
>   let operation.

**Addendum:**
I really have the problem to understand what cause your problems. Based on my guessing, i made the following MWE, which should show, that you can use my first MWE in your image on the following way (it is just dummy case, which should be simply extend to your real image):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=A]
        let \n1 = {2} in
        coordinate[label=above:$N$] (B) at ( \n1,\n1)
        coordinate[label=below:$O$] (O) at (-\n1,0)
        (0,0)  arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=\n1];
\draw[name path=C] (O) -- (B);
\fill[red,
      name intersections={of=A and C, by={D}}] (D) circle (2pt)
                                                   node[right=2mm] {intersection D};
\fill[gray] (O) circle (2pt)    (B) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. I only show you, how to solve problem you indicate in your question. If this is not a problem, what it is? Please edit your question accordingly. Draw arc can be used in determining of intersection with some other line.

Comment: I have edited the question.  Since I am working on a specific complicated example which i am using for publication, there are many different issues I could ask about.  This question is specifically about getting arc to accept a let operation in the same syntax that is working for coefficients and draw commands in my actual tikzpicture.